# VBA Worksheet_change when a new row has been added, insert today's date

Tags: vba, excel

i tried to use the formula =Today() on the table of my database and when i try to insert a new row the next day, the whole data even the previous dates had been replace with the current day's date. Is there anyway to prevent it ? Or is it possible to use worksheet_change to update the date's column when new row had been inserted and the new role's date column will have the current day date and the following day when i update again it wont be replaced? Please advise thanks

Comment: Every time your sheet gets updated, every single value will be set to the current date because every row gets updated. You should try to write a macro for this, which updates the whole sheet but only changes the value currently added.

Comment: Another suggestion, before adding that new row in the next day, why you are not Pasting the Value of yesterday's date? **(Simply copy and paste values)** As long as you don't want that date to be changed, you should rescue it from `=Today()` formula to prevent it from changing.

Comment: You are not expecting an answer like press **CTRL + ;** button, are you?

Comment: @Mertinc oh good idea, i can have a today's date in my form and when it get's saved i can copy and paste values to the database.. Great idea man. But was wondering if WorkSheet_change can be included instead of doing the copy and pasting

Comment: @RomcelGeluz yo Romcel! great to see you again. Of course not that xD i wanted something like a macro that is able to record todays date when the row is inputted. something about worksheet_change if i can remember clearly

Comment: I added the copy and paste values answer below ZQ7, as I don't know the structure and layout of your worksbook, I didn't understand clearly whay you would like to do with `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZQ7, this answer is as I mentioned in the comments, finds the =`TODAY()` formula cell and paste it's values to it's current cell. Then you can add your new row and run the rest of your code..

```
Option Explicit

Sub prevenddate()
Dim mert As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Cells.Find(What:="=TODAY()", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Copy
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

## And here is the desired answer!

This below code, firstly looks for any `=TODAY()` formula in worksheet, and if the result is *today's date* it doesn't do anything. But if it's different then *today's date* then it simply does **`Paste Values`**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRw As Long, myCl As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
On Error GoTo 10

myRw = ActiveCell.Row
myCl = ActiveCell.Column

        ws.Cells.Find(What:="=TODAY()", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
  If ActiveCell.Value <> Date Then

        Cells.Find(What:="=TODAY()", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Copy
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
End If
10
  ws.Cells(myRw, myCl).Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: But is it possible to change it into worksheet_change instead of activating the macro manually?

Comment: Ah now I got what you mean. But when (after which change) you would like macro to run (in which condition)?

Comment: well i was wishing for a more automated one. But it's okay i think your macro works just as well. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: I will add your requested feature very soon mate don't worry, wait on the line!

Comment: @ZQ7 please see my edited answer above. I've created a `Worksheet_Change` event, firstly looks for any `=TODAY()` formula in worksheet, and if the result is **today's date** it doesn't do anything. But if it's different then *today's date* then it simply does `Paste Values`

Answer (score 1):

From [Determine whether user is adding or deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479721/determine-whether-user-is-adding-or-deleting-rows) by breetdj I write this code. Try to put it in the sheet module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static LR As Long
Dim Table as range
Set Table = Me.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
If LR = 0 Then
    LR = Table.Rows.Count
    Exit Sub
End If
If Table.Rows.Count < LR Or Table.Cells(Table.Rows.Count, 1) <> "" Then Exit Sub
Table.Cells(Table.Rows.Count, 1) = Date
LR = LR + 1
End Sub
```

Change "ListObjects(1)" with the name of the table, and change the column number with your desired column

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
Public Function MyToday() As Date
MyToday = CDate(Now() \ 1)
End Function
```

and should be called like

```
MyToday()
```

Comment: You can achieve the same effect as `MyToday()` by just saying `Date()` (the VBA function that returns today's date) without the need for an extra function.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code on Sheet Module.

The code will insert a Date in column A if you input something in column B starting from Row2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Long
On Error GoTo SkipError
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    r = Target.Row
    If Target <> "" Then
        If Cells(r, "A") = "" Then
            Cells(r, "A") = Date
        End If
    Else
        Cells(r, "A") = ""
    End If
End If
SkipError:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 'Dim Rg As Range
 'Dim G As Integer
 'Dim varno As Long
  With Sheet1
  Range("J5:J5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("j5:j218")
 
 'Range("L8").Formula = "=IF(AND(F5="",G5="",H5=""),"",I4+F5-G5-H5)"
 

'Range("L8").Formula = ""

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Range("L8").Formula = "=IF(AND(F5="",G5="",H5=""),"",I4+F5-G5-H5)"
i try but it does not appear