# Determine if adding or deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking at the code noted in: [Determine whether user is adding or deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479721/determine-whether-user-is-adding-or-deleting-rows)

I can't figure out how to properly define the range mentioned: "define a range name such as `RowMarker =$A$1000`"

Which causes this line of code to error: `Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange`

Could someone give me a hand on how to properly define the range and where I need to do it ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64. So, select the range and then use the name box, type the name and then press enter.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I was missing.