# Prevent a user from adding or removing row(s) of a Range, but allow him to do so on another Range on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My sheet contains 2 named ranges **Titles** (A11:O15) and **Contents** (A18:O30).

I'm looking for a way to prevent a user to add or remove any row(s) of
**Titles**, but he must be able to edit its content.

On the other hand **Contents** can be modified without any restriction by the user.

How can I protect the first 17 lines of my sheet so that they can be edited but prevent the addition or removal of rows before the row 17 ?

Comment: So "*I'm looking for a way to prevent a user to add or remove any row(s) of Headers, but he must be able to edit its content.*" means able to edit the contents of the headers?

Comment: Yes, user can't add or remove rows from this range but he can edit the content of the already existing rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can offer is a workaround based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479837/17017616

First you create a `named Range` for the the cells you do not want the user add/remove rows and/or columns. In my example the name of that range is `protected_Area` and it spreads over 32 cells in total.

Next you add this code to the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const referenceCellCount = 32
    Static recursionGuard As Boolean
    Dim rngProt As Range
    
    
    If recursionGuard = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set rngProt = ThisWorkbook.Names("protected_Area").RefersToRange
  
   ' Adding or removing Rows in the protected area will
   ' change the size of the range and thus the total count of cells
    If referenceCellCount = rngProt.Cells.Count Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    recursionGuard = True
    Application.Undo
    recursionGuard = False
    MsgBox "Foo must not..."

End Sub
```

Make sure that `referenceCellCount` matches your case.

Comment: yeah, I'm working on something similar also using Application.Undo. Seams to be the only solution

Comment: Please mind that the answer does not yet cover the case where the user deletes many rows, so that the `protected_Area` is "empty" and cannot be converted to a range (#REF error).